# How to migrate data from in-memory DB to NSSQLiteStoreType DB in Core Data?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

In my OSX app I have two instances of DB: one is using NSSQLiteStoreType and another one NSInMemoryStoreType. The data models are identical.

When the app is running it uses in-memory DB instance to persist data. After I'm done working with my app, I would like to store all the data collected to NSSQLiteStoreType instance.

I'm pretty new to this type of data migration.

Does anyone have any suggestions or tips on how I can do it?!

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To migrate from one store type to another you need to use `-migratePersistentStore: toURL: options: withType: error:` on the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  This will create the new store.

However, I am confused as to why you are doing this.  If you are looking for maximum performance then you probably just want to use a binary store from the beginning.  That will load everything into memory and write everything out to disk when you save.  No migration needed.

In memory stores are intended for transient data and migrating out of an in memory store is fairly CPU intensive.

Comment: Oh, well...I didn't know that binary store is in-memory

Comment: It is atomic.  It is loaded into memory during use and then saved atomically when you `-save:`.  All or nothing so it is effectively an in memory store that persists to disk.

Comment: wait, but what is the difference between binary store and sqlite store if for my sqlite store I write to disk on save: operation only as well?

Comment: SQLite writes to a SQLite file.  Binary writes to a proprietary formatted file.  SQLite is not atomic, Binary is.  SQLite loads back into memory only what is currently being used, Binary loads everything.